# UWP Rotating SunBurst

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, rotation, 2d

I'm pretty new when it comes to rotating in UWP, so I might be going about this the wrong way.

In my app I want a sunburst image to rotate in a square a lot like this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nysZq7eUOMA). I have created a 1000x1000px sunburst image. I have tried rotating it via XAML and C#, but my efforts produce a rotating square see image.[image]

I have tried the following methods:

XAML:

```
<Page.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard" x:Name="sb" >
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RotateImage" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)" 
                            From="0" To="360" RepeatBehavior="Forever" BeginTime="00:00:00.000" Duration="00:00:5.000" />
        </Storyboard>
    </Page.Resources>

<Grid RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                       Width="300" Height="300">
                    <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/SunBurst.png" x:Name="RotateImage" Stretch="Fill">
                        <Image.RenderTransform>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="0" CenterX="150" CenterY="150"  />
                        </Image.RenderTransform>
                    </Image>
            </Grid>
```

C#:

```
BitmapImage btpImg = new BitmapImage();
            btpImg.UriSource = new Uri(@"ms-appx:///Assets/SunBurst.png");

            Image img = new Image
            {
                Source = btpImg,
                RenderTransform = new RotateTransform()
                {
                    CenterX = 150,
                    CenterY = 150
                },
                Stretch = Stretch.Fill
            };

            Grid rect = new Grid
            {
                Width = 300,
                Height = 300,
            };

            rect.Children.Add(img);


            Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
            DoubleAnimation rotateAnimation = new DoubleAnimation()
            {
                From = 0,
                To = 360,
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)),
                RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever,

            };

            Storyboard.SetTarget(rotateAnimation, rect);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(rotateAnimation, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)");

            storyboard.Children.Add(rotateAnimation);

            Board.Children.Add(rect);

            storyboard.Begin();
```

If anyone has any pro tips on getting the desired effect I would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: you need to have the image size greater than the *viewable* area of the screen you are showing it on ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have the solution!

First I needed to change my storyboard to

```
<Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard" x:Name="sb" >
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RotateImage" 
                             EnableDependentAnimation="True"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Brush.RelativeTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)" 
                            From="0" To="360" RepeatBehavior="Forever" BeginTime="00:00:00.000" Duration="00:00:5.000" />
        </Storyboard>
```

Then I changed holding my image in a grid to a rectangle.

```
<Rectangle RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                       Width="300" Height="300" x:Name="bb">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/SunBurst.png" x:Name="RotateImage" Stretch="Fill">
                        <ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5" ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5" />
                        </ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
                    </ImageBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it larger and set **RenderTransformOrigin**:

```
<Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/SunBurst.png" x:Name="RotateImage" Stretch="Fill" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2"/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am still getting the large rotating square. Is there a better parent control than a grid or canvas to rotate an image?